# Eclipse makes incremental build do not using pom file properly

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, build

I have quite non-standard web app configuration: my web.xml file is located not in the WEB-INF folder, but is copied by maven from some another place (please don't ask why).
For that I'm using maven-war-plugin approach in my pom.xml: `<webXml>${project.some.webapp.path}/web.xml</webXml>`

It works fine when I call mvn install.
But, when I make 'Build project' (incremental build) in eclipse - it doesn't copy web.xml into the WEB-INF folder, as well as other maven-war-plugin features, like webResources. (it seems its just doesn't use its configuration at all during the incr build)

What can you advice in my case?

Comment: javagirl - If you are going to downvote my answers (especially on such flimsy grounds), I'm going to stop wasting my time answering your questions.  You asked for advice on what to do, and I gave it.  If you don't want advice, don't ask for it ... and don't downvote people who give it.  We'll ignore the fact that 3 people thought it was good advice ...

Comment: @StephenC please don't take it so personally. What about being a professional? your answer wasn't been answer to _my_ question, it happens, what is your problem? If I can't downvote inappropriate, populist, obvious answers then what the downvote button is supposed for?

Comment: @StephenC and btw, downvoting in retort is just another example of not being a professional.

Comment: my downvote is because your question asks for advice, but you don't actually want advice.  A question that misleads the people into wasting their time on answers that you don't actually want, is a bad question.  Nothing personal.

Comment: @StephenC you wrong in thinking that I didn't want _any_ advice. I didn't want advice like you gave. and btw you still taking it personally

Comment: don't presume to think that you know what I'm thinking.

Comment: @StephenC Fine. Hope now finally you'll stop wasting your precious time on this stupid confrontation

Answer (score 0):

There's currently no option for this (I'm looking for one right now). In fact, it would work if there was an option in Eclipse to always run a full build (that's what you do when invoking «Build project») instead of an auto-build that runs an incremental-build, which only look at resources directory (by doing a delta). So many actions are not performed, such as copy-resources and so on, even if you've set up other directories, maven doesn't look into these because of the ignoreDelta incremental option.

I'm looking for a way to force the full build in every case, but it may need to change the core code of Eclipse.